Visual Studio Code on Mac - .what() Method does not show error description in Terminal
maybe one of you know why I don't get the error description in VSC on mac in the terminal.
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdexcept>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v{1,4,6,2,76,45};

    try
    {
        std::cout << v.at(10) << '\n';
    }
    catch(const std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << '\n';
    }


    std::cout << "Programmende!" << '\n';
    return 0;
}

That is the code, normally I would expect a error like:
vector::_M_range_check: __n (which is 10) >= this->size() (which is 6)

In the terminal it only shows:
vector
Programmende!

Thanks in advance! :)

Which compiler?

The Compiler: g++

Can you add the output of g++ --version?

This is property of clangs standard library: https://godbolt.org/z/Mb89bKd5x on MacOS clang is aliased as gcc.
